# Group controls dynamically in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls, grouping

I have of list of structures and create controls (labels, textboxes,...) based on information from this list. Can I group the controls so that I can run through all controls and build up the list again? Any ideas on how this is done best?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the `List<Control>`.

```
Dim sampleControls as new List(Of Control)
sampleControls.Add(new Label())
```